# Python script using requests to post files to Django app - Nothing in request.FILES

Tags: django, python-2.7, python-requests

Using Django 1.5 and Python 2.7.3.

Simple example to demonstrate my problem. I can't send files to our Django webapp using Python + requests. I'm using a script that resides on my computer and testing using Django's built in server (also running locally).

I've followed [the example here](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/quickstart/#post-a-multipart-encoded-file) on how to post files but `requests.FILES` is empty.

#### script.py

```
import requests
import os

url="http://<myurl>/upload"
files={'file':('myfile.txt', open('myfile.txt', 'rb'))}
r=requests.post(url, files = files)
r.text  # Number of files in request.FILES: 0
```

#### views.py

```
def upload(request):
  return HttpResponse("Number of files in request.FILES: {0}".format(len(request.FILES)))
```

**EDIT**

Headers: `{'date': 'Tue, 11 Jun 2013 15:10:13 GMT', 'content-type': 'text/html; charset=utf-8', 'server': 'WSGIServer/0.1 Python/2.7.3'}`

The URL is correct (I can see the response text in my script). The script works when I point the URL to `http://httpbin.org/post` as in the example.

Is there something in my `requests.post` that I'm missing?

Comment: Can you post the request headers sent to the server? Normally Django wouldn't populate `request.FILES` if there isn't multipart/encode in the headers.

Comment: Edited to include the headers from `r.headers`.

Comment: This is from the docs: > Note that request.FILES will only contain data if the request method was POST and the <form> that posted the request has the attribute enctype="multipart/form-data". Otherwise, request.FILES will be empty. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/file-uploads/

Comment: When printing `request` in my view I see `CONTENT_TYPE: multipart/form-data`. I'm not sure how I'd set the `enctype` using requests.

Comment: If you see it then is good! I'll recommend something, try to post a file to the view from a web page (some html you hack to do it). If the file gets uploaded, see how the request is conformed and try to simulate it in your script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In a moment of slight embarrassment, it turns out you really NEED the trailing forward-slash in the URL.

`url="http://<myurl>/upload/"`